# HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing (Occasional) - SpringMVC Default Controller Request Mapping HTTP Method?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following code which represents an Ajax POST request:

```
@RequestMapping("/participant/insertEvent")
public boolean insertEvent(Principal principal, @RequestBody String json, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
     //...
     //return true or false
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    url : '/app/participant/insertEvent',   
    data : JSON.stringify({'p1': p1, 'p2' : p2})        
});
```

The app is deployed in Production and everything has been working with many users the whole week.

This morning I got the following production issue at this method (`insertEvent`):

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public boolean 
app.controller.participant.AjaxOperationsController.insertEvent(java.security.Principal,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:161) at        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130) at           org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124) at 

    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) at ...
```

I'm wondering, is it because I didn't explicitly specify this is a `method={RequestMethod.POST}` ?

But if I don't specify an HTTP method, what is the default?

However, if this is the issue, then why does the app work 99% of the time, and not for that one user?

Comment: If you read the Javadoc of @RequestMapping, the default for `method` is `{}`. This means it maps all HTTP methods by default.

Comment: Anyway, if you send a GET, you'll get that error because a GET request doesn't have a body.

Comment: Thanks, but as you see I didn't send a GET. My Ajax JS code sent a POST. The server received whatever was coming in, in this case a POST. And another thing we know is this code works 99% of the time. So what could explain this **rare/occasional** error?

Comment: If you send a POST without a body, same error. That json is required.

Comment: You can set `required=false` on `@RequestBody` to make it optional.

Comment: Thanks again. But the JSON is always required, the operation requires it. So I guess my question is: What could result in an empty JSON being passed? Is it some kind of timeout or outage? Once again: 99.9% of the time this issue does not occur.

Comment: The error would be a different one. Are you sure that ajax call is the only consumer?

Comment: Yes, pretty sure. Could it be the size or encoding of a text area field (which I'm using as one of the JSON fields, in the stringified data)?

Comment: Maybe `JSON.stringify` returns null or empty string if something wrong happens. I'm not familiar with Javascript but I would suspect the client side here.

Comment: I found the cause!!! I was including an un-encoded % sign in a TextArea (e.g. "90%") in my JSON! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the error was caused by including in the JSON **an un-encoded % (percent) special char coming from a TextArea** value.

Comment: Why a "%" character will make Spring not recognise your JSON?