# Occasional Error: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public boolean

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

> UPDATE For the **affected few** users, it looks like they are submitting
> **both** POST and GET requests for each operation, even though they should
> only submit 1 POST request! As mentioned, 99% of users work perfectly
> fine with the POST Ajax request below, so why are we getting double POST/GET
> pairs from some users?
> e.g

> 1.2.3.4 - - [10/Nov/2020:09:44:20 -0500] "POST /system/participant/insertEvent HTTP/1.1" 200 4  followed by

> 1.2.3.4 - - [10/Nov/2020:09:44:20 -0500] "GET /system/participant/insertEvent HTTP/1.1" 200 4

What could explain *occasional* (not constant) errors in an application deployed to Production,

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public boolean
```

on an Ajax method,

```
@RequestMapping("/insertEvent")
public boolean insertEvent(Principal principal, @RequestBody String json, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    

        participantService.insertEvent(principal, json, (Integer)request.getSession().getAttribute("dataId"), true);
        return true;
}
```

From the JS side, this server-side method is called as

```
$.ajax({
    type : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    url : '/insertEvent',   
    data : encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({'newEventStartTimestamp' : newEventStartTimestamp, 'newEventEndTimestamp' : newEventEndTimestamp, 
                           'newGuiEventID' : newEventID})) 
});
```

As mentioned, this code **works 99%** of the time in Production, but for some specific users or operations, it breaks.

In the past, we tied one occurrence of this issue to unencoded request body that [included special chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452223/httpmessagenotreadableexception-required-request-body-is-missing-occasional) (% typed in one form field), but that has since been resolved. Now in JS we do `encodeURIComponent` as you can see. What are other potential causes of this occasional rare error?

MORE INFO: 1) When these `HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing` errors occur, they all come from the same few users; 2) Those users are **unaffected**. They successfully complete their operations, so this is some kind of a side-effect problem. I initially thought the JSON could be empty or corrupted, but they would have failed if that was the case.

My Java `@RequestMapping` methods don't explicitly specify a POST method, but the JS call **does** specify the POST data type. It [says online](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) that

> The HTTP method parameter has no default. So, if we don't specify a
> value, it's going to map to any HTTP request.

But is that a problem? It would catch all types, and I'm passing in POST from the JS side.

Comment: What does "*it breaks*" mean? What is the specific error? As you mentioned, the `Required request body...` error is probably due to the `GET`. As an aside: specifying the HTTP method for the endpoint is good practice. Does a `GET /insertEvent` make sense for your application? If not, then specifying e.g. `@PostMapping` would cause that endpoint to return a `405 Method Not Allowed` - as expected. Perhaps this would allow you to note where exactly this `GET` is coming from.

Comment: As I wote in my update at the top, the problem is that both POST and GET are being submitted for some rare users. There should be no `GET /insertEvent` ever for any users. Something is submitting a *pair* of POST/GET for those very rare users.

Comment: Yes, but you also said that the users for which this happens are unaffected. So do they receive an error, or are they unaffected? It's very likely that something in your client code is performing the separate `GET /insertEvent` call, and one way to figure out what it is, is to disallow that call in the first place.

Comment: They do not receive any error and are unaffected. But we get exception emails sent to us, because we record all exceptions that happen in the system. The users go on and complete their operations.That's because their POST from that double-pair is successful. The question is why some users/browsers submit both a GET and a POST, when the JS clearly specifies the POST.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a redirect statement somewhere after that `ajax` call? I do not see any callbacks on `success`. What happens after the request is sent?

Comment: It's basic `.then` with `promise`'s. E.g., `$.ajax(..).then(function() { .. }).then(function() { .. }).fail(..)`. The structure is Promise Returned -> Then -> Fail. And as I said, 99% of the time this works reliably, it's not reproducible most of the time.